# Using EU plug in UK shaver socket

Tags: power-supply

A friend of mine keeps charging a device with a Europlug (the Type C version without grounding, which has two pins) in the 230V shaver socket (BS 4573) in his UK home. I have a bad feeling every time he does it, partly because there is this subtle humming noise happening, but mostly out of principle to be honest. But both UK and Europe have 230V/50Hz, so that's not an issue. And the pins seem to fit more or less. I certainly can't convince him to stop (or stop trying to convince him in case it's actually fine) if I don't know more about it, so I'm asking here.

**Edit**: the device in question is either a hair clipper or electric toothbrush with 100-240V AC, 50-60Hz and 0.4-1.4W (toothbrush) or 7W (clipper)

Is it safe to put a Europlug into a 230V UK shaving socket? And if not: why?

Comment: Which device is being charged? What does that device says about current, voltage or power rating?

Comment: Yes, why would it be unsafe? If you plug that plug in continental Europe it isn't grounded neither.

Comment: @Swedgin So I shouldn't be concerned? I guess I mainly didn't like my friend's "if it fits it's fine!" attitude considering that electrical power CAN be dangerous. That's why I wanted to ask here. Also, I'm still not sure where the humming comes from. It doesn't happen with other sockets.

Comment: AFAIK I wouldn't be worried. If the device needed to be grounded, it would have a ground pin, and you wouldn't be able to plug it in. The power output of the UK socket is in the acceptable range of the device, so also no problem. The humming is probably due to a not so good connection, but maybe someone else can chip in too.

Comment: A BS 4573 shaver socket has an isolating transformer: the transformer may be what is generating the hum.

Comment: @Swedgin it seems you don't understand how an UK shaver socket works. It has a built-in current limiting and isolation transformer, therefore only meant for powering low power devices with matching plug and consuming power like a shaver would, as they are suitable loads for that transformer. It is not intended to power arbitrary loads like chargers with switch mode power supplies.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it certainly is in mine, when used for a shaver or electric toothbrush.  Strangely plugging in the (non-rechargeable) shaver but not switching it on is enough to get the hum - some effect of mechanical coupling.

Comment: @Justme they're 20W, so a normal phone charger should be fine (~5-10W gives plenty of margin for derating into that load, besides, many shavers are reachargeable with a PSU/charge circuit of some kind), but not a laptop charger or the latest fast chargers.  I have used this to my advantage when I only had access to shaver sockets (on a campsite), but it's a pity adapting to take a UK mains plug adds so much bulk (in a backpacking context where every little counts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An UK shaver socket has a built-in current limiting and isolation transformer, therefore only meant for powering low power devices with matching plug and consuming low power in a similat way like a shaver would draw power from it.

Only these are suitable loads for that transformer.

As shaver plug is not intended to give power to arbitrary loads like chargers with switch mode power supplies in them.

The risks are small but it is not meant for other purposes. Drawing too much power can overheat the isolation trasformer, but it seems that power ratings are not exceeded. Also the output voltage can vary due to load so some chargers may not get nice and stable low impedance mains voltage they would like to have from standard plug.

And chargers are switch mode power supplies, so they tend to consume current at the peak of sine waves only, which may explain what generates the noise to begin with.

Comment: You seem to imply that UK shavers do not have SMPS in them - is that correct?

Comment: I see. So as long as low-power devices like shavers (or hair clippers and electric tooth brushes as in my case) are used it should be fine? And do I understand correctly that there is a difference in whether these devices are being charged or powered directly?

Comment: Yes the shaver sockets are different, they don't have mains voltage connected directly like normal sockets, shaver sockets are special and are connected to mains via a low power isolating transformer. If a device is not equipped with a shaver plug, it most likely is not meant to be connected to a shaver socket and should not be connected to one. Unless the device manual says it's OK to do so.

Comment: @Tobitobitobi It's really down to whether the wattage of the appliance is within the limit of the small isolation transformer in the shaver socket.  Many appliances these days are electronic, and many are rechargeable.  My UK-model shaver has a rechargeable battery inside.  The charger has a standard UK 2-pin shaver plug on it, and is clearly meant to be plugged into a shaver socket.